# Angular custom method on $resource with .then() function causing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my Angular service:

```
return $resource(BASE + '/cases/:id',
    {id: '@id'}, {
        status: {method: 'GET', params: {status: '@status'}}
});
```

When using the method added to the `$resource` definition along with the promise's `.then()` function, I'm getting an error:

```
Cases.status({status: 'pending'})
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        $scope.cases.pending = res.data.cases;
    })
    .then(function() {
        $scope.tabbed.pending = true;
    });
```

After the above snippet is run, the error I get is:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line: `.then(function(res) {`

Can I not use these functions as I usually do when I'm using an extra method defined on the `$resource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `$promise` of `$resource` object which will call success function when actual promise gets resolved & then you could proceed with the promise chain.

**CODE**

```
Cases.status({status: 'pending'})
.$promise
.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    $scope.cases.pending = res.data.cases;
})
.then(function(cases) {
    $scope.tabbed.pending = true;
});
```

Comment: I added the return statement and there was no difference.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff do try with `$promise.then` see my update

Comment: @NoahMatisoff does it make any change..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $promise in order to access the promise is created on that call, like this:

```
Cases.get({id: 123}).$promise
  .then(function (success) {
    //do something
}).then(function (error) {
    //do something else
})
```

Or you can send both functions as callbacks:

```
Cases.get({id: 123}, function (success) {
  //do something
}, function (error) {
  //do something else
});
```

**Tip**
You don't *have* to add a new method to that $resource to send a GET to the same url, you can just have your $resource be plain:

```
//... code
return $resource(BASE + '/cases'});
```

and when you pass the parameters to it (if you are passing them as in the example) it will match the keys according to the object so you can just say:

```
Cases.get({status: 'something'}).$promise
  .then(function(success){
    //... code
  })
  .then(function(err){
    //... code
  });

Cases.get({id: 123}).$promise
  .then(function(success){
    //... code
  })
  .then(function(err){
    //... code
  });
```